# C++11 direct-list-initialization syntax

Tags: c++, opengl-es, c++11, initialization

After reading up on list-initialization and its various flavours, I decided to test out some features in an openGL ES app I'm writing using Xcode and Objective-C++, until I ran into something rather obscure.

I've known about (and frequently implement) the conventional C style structure initialization using the following syntax to initialize POD, such as a GLKVector2, for example:

```
GLKVector2 point = { 0,0 };    //copy-initialized
```

but this approach may not always be what's intended by the programmer. So, by removing the assignment (and a needless copy construction operation), in favour of direct-initilization, one would assume (from the documentation) the above declaration would appear like so:

```
GLKVector2 point{ 0,0 };    //direct-initialized, but generates compile error
```

However, the compiler doesn't complain when the code looks like this:

```
GLKVector2 point{ { 0,0 } };
```

To me, this appears as `point` is being direct-initialized from a temporary created from the inner structure `{ 0,0 }` and thus not offering any advantage over the first approach; the temporaries still have to be allocated and deallocated.

Or perhaps this issue is simply the nature of the union/struct layout used by GLKit types confusing the compiler.

Some clarification on this odd syntax, before further implementation in the code, would be much appreciated

Comment: Could you post the definition of `GLKVector2`? Constructors should be enough

Comment: Also, what compiler version are you using?

Comment: "*and a needless copy construction operation*" FYI: you didn't remove one of these because one of those never happened. Copy-initialization doesn't actually copy anything. And copy-list-initialization certainly does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer braces delimit the initializer for the object itself, the inner braces are the initializer for a member inside the object, e.g.

```
GLKVector2 v = { initializers-for-members };
```

where `initializers-for-members` is `{ 0, 0 }` because the type has an array member, of two elements, and you initialize an array of two members with `{ a, b }`.

C++ supports "brace elision" (8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr] paragraph 11) which means nested braces can be left out of the initializer under certain circumstances, but in C++11 brace elision is only allowed for copy-initialization.  This is why you don't need two sets of braces for the copy-init case, but do need them for direct-init.

Since C++11 was completed the rules have been changed by [DR 1270](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1270) to allow brace elision in the direct-list-initialization case too, but that's a change made to the post-C++11 draft and not widely supported yet.

Answer (score 3):

According to [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKVector2/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010978-CH3-SW1) `GLKVector2` is:

```
union _GLKVector2
   {
   struct { float x, y; };
   struct { float s, t; };
      float v[2];
};
typedef union _GLKVector2 GLKVector2;
```

That's why you need double braces, you're initializing by initializing a union member. Member-wise aggregate initialization occurs *in-place*. If it were a flat structure, your single-braces assumption would work. This also happens when initializing an `std::array` (e.g. `std::array<int, 2> a{{1, 2}}`) because it's a POD aggregate, and no temporary C arrays are involved.

You should look at [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

### EDIT

Actually, looking up the docs, there're rules about *brace elision* (only allowed in copy-initialization context) that may be of interest.

Comment: The underlying problem IIRC is that in C++11 brace elision isn't allowed with direct-initialization syntax. I believe this is going to be fixed. Also, the double brace syntax for initializing std::array, `std::array<int, 2> a{{1, 2}}`, is implementation specific. The standard only specifies that `std::array` can be initialized with the copy-initialization syntax.