# Different behavior of c++11 list-initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization

Please consider the following code:

```
class A {
private:
  std::string s;
public:
  A() = delete;
  A(const A&) = delete;
  A(A&&) = delete;
  A(const std::string &a) : s(a) {}
};
```

Now, I would like to initialize an array of A using list initialization. g++ (4.9.1) could successfully build the following code:

```
int main() {
  A arr[2] = {{"a"}, {"b"}};
  return 0;
}
```

But, it failed for the following code:

```
class Aggr {
private:
  A arr[2];
public:
  Aggr() : arr{{"a"}, {"b"}} {}
};
```

The error messages are,

```
test.cc: In constructor ‘Aggr::Aggr()’:
test.cc:22:28: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(A&&)’
   Aggr() : arr{{"a"}, {"b"}} {}
                            ^          
test.cc:11:3: note: declared here
   A(A&&) = delete;
   ^
```

That said, a list-initializer tries to call a move constructor for initializing an array inside of a class. That code, however, was successfully built by clang v3.5 without any warnings.
So, I would like to know what the C++11 (or later version) specifies rules with respect to list-initialization. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ZivS an rvalue reference

Comment: possibly relevant to your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685551/how-to-initialize-array-of-classes-with-deleted-copy-constructor-c11

Comment: @marcinj, yes, it's the same. Looks like a GCC bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63707

Comment: @JonathanWakely it looks very similar. But there are differences, as there is no user defined destructor involved, and the problem depends on A data members, but also on the way A move ctor are defined.  See testcases in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64887

Comment: @Christophe, what you've missed is that the `std::string` member here makes the destructor non-trivial, just like the user-defined destructor does in the other example. It's the same bug, I've closed it as a duplicate.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I've seen your edit in the bug and I agree. The strange thing to mention are the two last testcases, because thebehaviour is different with an implicit move operator and a user defined one.

Answer (score 2):

Reading again and again the standard, I think this is a bug.

**What does the standard say ?**

> **8.5.1/2** : When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as specified in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list are taken
>   as initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing
>   subscript or member order. Each member is copy-initialized from the
>   corresponding initializer-clause.

It is explained that:

> **8.5/14** :  (...) is called copy-initialization. [ Note: Copy-initialization may invoke a move (12.8). —end note ]

But I found no evidence in 12.8 that in your specific case a move would be required.

> **8.5.4/3** Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. If T has an initializer-list constructor, the argument
>   list consists of the initializer list as a single argument; otherwise,
>   the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.
>   The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen
>   through overload resolution (13.3).

So in principle you code should work !

**Is it a bug ?  Trying the experimental way**

I commented out the delete of the move constructor, to benefit from the implicit move constructor.  Strangely,  I then got the following error message:

```
    Compilation error   time: 0 memory: 3232 signal:0

prog.cpp: In constructor 'Aggr::Aggr()':
prog.cpp:19:28: error: use of deleted function 'A::A(const A&)'
   Aggr() : arr{{"a"}, {"b"}} {}
                            ^
prog.cpp:10:3: note: declared here
   A(const A&) = delete
```

So now he complains about a missing copy constructor !

Even more strangely, I then provided my own move constructor instead of the implicit one : here it compiled the code successfully !!

Finally I provided both a copy and a move and added some tracing:

```
class A {
private:
  std::string s;
public:
  A() = delete;
  A(const A&)  { std::cout<<"copy\n";} //= delete;
  A(A&&) { std::cout<<"move\n";} //= delete;
  A(const std::string &a) : s(a) {  std::cout<<"string ctor\n";}
};
```

And when I create an `Aggr` object, it just displays:

```
string ctor 
string ctor
```

showing that the array member is initialized form the string constructor using copy elision as we would have expected.

All these tests were performed with gcc-9.4.2 on ideone with C++14 option.

**Conclusion**

The fact that the same code fails to compile with implicit move ctor and succeeds with a user-defined move ctor looks very seriously like a bug.

The fact that the move constructor is not used when it's available reinforces this impression.

Consequently, I've reported [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64887).