# Class member array of objects without default constructor and deleted copy constructors initialization

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class called 'Container' in which three (known at compile time) objects of class DontCopyMe must be stored. Class DontCopyMe has non-default constructor and deleted copy constructors. How can I initialize Containter?

Sample code:

```
#include <string>

class DontCopyMe
{
    public:
        DontCopyMe(const unsigned int SomeInt, const std::string & SomeString): SomeInt(SomeInt), SomeString(SomeString)
        {
        }
        DontCopyMe(const DontCopyMe &) = delete;
        DontCopyMe & operator = (const DontCopyMe &) = delete;
        DontCopyMe(DontCopyMe &&) = delete;
        DontCopyMe & operator = (DontCopyMe &&) = delete;

    private:
        const unsigned int SomeInt;
        const std::string SomeString;
};

class Container
{
    public:
        Container(): Array{{1, "A"}, {2, "B"}, {3, "C"}}
        {

        }

    private:
        DontCopyMe Array[3];
};

int main()
{
    Container C;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course I'm getting:

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'Container::Container()':                                                                                                                                                                                            
main.cpp:22:56: error: use of deleted function 'DontCopyMe::DontCopyMe(DontCopyMe&&)'                                                                                                                                                         
         Container(): Array{{1, "A"}, {2, "B"}, {3, "C"}}
```

Comment: Note: `clang++ 3.6.2` compiles without errors. `g++ 5.2.0` gives the errors you posted.

Comment: If it's always three elements, you can cheat your way around the issue by storing three individual `DontCopyMe` members.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63707

Comment: related: [How to initialize array of classes with deleted copy constructor (C++11)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26685551/3953764)

Comment: These aren't movable either - the title should emphasize that too. Perhaps "initialize array of T, where T is neither copyable nor movable"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clang++ 3.6.2` compiles your code. `g++ 5.2.0` does not.

[According to this report, this is a bug in g++.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63707)

---

Here's a (**nasty**) workaround, for the moment: use [`std::aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage), [`placement new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) and explicit destructor calls:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Container
{
    private:
        using Storage = typename std::aligned_storage
        <
            sizeof(DontCopyMe), 
            alignof(DontCopyMe)
        >::type;

    public:
        Container()
        {
            // Construct an instance of `DontCopyMe` in the memory
            // location starting at `&Array[0]`.
            new (&Array[0]) DontCopyMe{1, "A"};

            // ...
            new (&Array[1]) DontCopyMe{2, "B"};
            new (&Array[2]) DontCopyMe{3, "C"};

            // You can also (and should) use a for-loop.
        }  

        ~Container()
        {
            // Interpret the bytes at location `&Array[2]` as if
            // they were a `DontCopyMe` instance, then call the
            // `~DontCopyMe()` destructor on it.
            (reinterpret_cast<DontCopyMe*>(&Array[2]))->~DontCopyMe();

            // ...
            (reinterpret_cast<DontCopyMe*>(&Array[1]))->~DontCopyMe();
            (reinterpret_cast<DontCopyMe*>(&Array[0]))->~DontCopyMe();

            // You can also (and should) use a for-loop.
        }   

    private:
        Storage Array[3];
};
```

You'll have to implement move and copy operations for `Containers` that cleanup the aligned storage properly. You may want to wrap all `aligned_storage`-related code in an helper class.

---

You mentioned you require additional safety and constness. The best way to achieve this is wrapping `std::aligned_storage` in an helper class that will make sure you don't make mistakes.

Here's some code to get you started:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

template<typename T, std::size_t TSize>
struct ASImmutableArray
{
    private:
        using ThisType = ASImmutableArray<T, TSize>;

        using Storage = typename std::aligned_storage
        <
            sizeof(T),
            alignof(T)
        >::type;

        Storage data[TSize];

        template<typename... Ts>
        void initAt(std::size_t mIndex, Ts&&... mXs)
        {
            assert(mIndex >= 0 && mIndex < TSize);
            // assert the data was not initialized
            new (&data[mIndex]) T(std::forward<Ts>(mXs)...);
        }

        void deinitAt(std::size_t mIndex)
        {
            assert(mIndex >= 0 && mIndex < TSize);
            // assert the data was actually initialized
            reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[mIndex])->~T();
        }

    public:
        // ...


};
```

An idea is passing `std::tuple` instances in the constructor of `ASImmutableArray`, and creating `T` instances in place using `placement new` at the correct indices by expanding the tuples and forwarding their contents to `T`'s constructor. The tuples would contain the same types as the types required to construct `T`.

You can also keep track of initialized/deinitialized items with an additional member boolean array (that can be disabled in release builds, and only used for verifying the correct usage of the class during development).

If you want an example of an (old) implementation of something similar, [this is something I've written for one of my libraries](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVUtils/blob/master/include/SSVUtils/GrowableArray/GrowableArray.hpp).

You can also check out [this tagged union implementation I've written](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVUtils/blob/master/include/SSVUtils/Union/Inc/Union.hpp) to see an example on how I use debug-only member variables that have no overhead in release-builds for additional safety.

Comment: This IS a solution, but absolutely not suitable for my needs. Right now I'm going to switch to clang and try again.

Comment: @peku33: Out of curiosity, why isn't it suitable?

Comment: It places objects on heap. In target solution the array is also marked as const so assigning later than in initializer list is not possible. It also allows to skip initialization of object and it won't show any error.

Comment: @peku33: Incorrect. It doesn't place the objects on the heap. `std::aligned_storage` is just a bunch of bytes. You can place them where you want, and in my example they're just a member of `Container`. It's equivalent to your desired code in terms of memory. You can solve your `const` issues and your `initialization issues` by creating a wrapper class around `std::aligned_storage` that makes sure you correctly initialize/deinitialize the memory.

Comment: Empirical proof that it does not make use of the heap: [ideone link](http://ideone.com/JCRvKX).